# How to create a stacked bar chart with gaps between values of each variables in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with creating a stacked bar chart in Python. I have data with 3 variables as below:

`A=[3,5,7] 
B=[4,5,7]
C=[2,3,4,5,6,7]`

I would like to create a bar chart with gaps of values of each variable as below bar chart with gaps between values of each variable :

[image]

Could anyone know how to create it in Python?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Update your post with what you have tried and why it is not working.

Comment: I don't know what kind of barchart here so don't know how to handle it? could you give any idea about what kind of chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may apply [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) to your project. There is a free [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/developer/) for developers and with the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) you can use these functions in Python.

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr
```

Start the session.

```
wolfSession = WolframLanguageSession();
A=[3,5,7];
B=[4,5,7];
C=[2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

Either the [`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html) or [`MatrixPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html) functions can be applied. These functions take 2D matrices so first need to convert the lists.

With [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) a matrix can be specified without explicitly setting values for all positions. Empty positions are set to `''` below.

```
pos=wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Flatten(
        wl.MapIndexed(
            wl.Function(wl.Rule([wl.First(wl.Slot(2)), wl.Slot(1)], wl.First(wl.Slot(2)))),
            [A,B,C],
            [2]
        ),
        1
    )
);
sparse = wolfSession.evaluate(wl.SparseArray(pos, wl.Automatic, ''));

print(wolfSession.evaluate(wl.Normal(sparse)))
```

> ```
> [['', '', 1, '', 1, '', 1], 
>  ['', '', '', 2, 2, '', 2], 
>  ['', 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
> ```

Using custom [`ColorRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorRules.html) and [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) to get a basic representation of your plot.  You can use these and many other options to get you precise look you

```
stacked=wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.ArrayPlot(
        sparse,
        AspectRatio = 1/4,
        ColorRules = wl.Flatten(
            [wl.Thread(wl.Rule(wl.Range(3),[wl.Green,wl.Orange,wl.Blue])),
            wl.Rule(wl.Blank(),wl.White)]
        ),
        FrameTicks = [
            [wl.Thread([range(1,4), ['A','B','C']]), wlexpr('None')],
            [
                wl.Thread([ 
                    wl.Range(7), 
                    list(map(lambda r: str(r)+'k', range(1,8)))
                ]), 
                wlexpr('None')
            ]
        ]
    )
);
```

Then [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) in one of the supported [Raster Image Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RasterImageFormats.html) or [Vector Graphics Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VectorGraphicsFormats.html).

```
wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Export(
        '<path with image filename>', 
        stacked
    )
)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Terminate session

```
wolfSession.terminate()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't run the code. When I run wolfSession = WolframLanguageSession(); The error is ValueError: Invalid kernel value. Expecting a filepath as a string.
I try to google the error but can't find the reason.

Comment: @LanPhuong You need to download the free engine that goes with the `wolframclient` package; [you can fine it here](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/).